# Editing the WooCommerce Lost Password Error Messages

Tags: woocommerce

There are two separate error messages on the WooCommerce Lost Password page: "Enter a username or email address." and "Invalid username or email." How do I edit these?

Answer (score 2):

this should do it. Add this to your current theme's functions.php.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_error', 'change_email_error');
function change_email_error( $message ) {
    if ($message == 'Enter a username or email address.' ) {
        $message = 'Enter a username';
    }
    if ($message == 'Invalid username or email.' ) {
        $message = 'Invalid username';
    }
    return $message;
}
```

A little explanation. Those error messages you mentioned are called by `wc_add_notice` like as follows:

```
wc_add_notice( __( 'Enter a username or email address.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid username or email.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
```

`wc_add_notice` has two params: `$message`, and `$notice_type`. Inside this function there's a filter to change the message: `$notices[ $notice_type ][] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_' . $notice_type, $message );`

Answer (score 0):

We are going to have to add a function to our functions.php, and then check what the current action is.

```
function login_message_example( $message ) {
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
```

If the current action is lostpassword, we would like the code to return a custom message.

```
if( $action == 'lostpassword' ) {
            $message = '<p class="message">Enter your email address, then check your inbox for the "reset password" link!</p>';
            return $message;
        }
```

A custom message is stored in the message variable and this variable gets returned. We just have to add one line:

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'login_message_example' );
```

This will allow the function to run.

The full code:

```
function login_message_example( $message ) {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
    if( $action == 'lostpassword' ) {
        $message = '<p class="message">Enter your email address, then check your inbox for the "reset password" link!</p>';
        return $message;
    }
    return;

    add_filter( 'login_message', 'login_message_example' );
}
```

Good luck!